# Count json occurrence inside array SQL

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

In my table, i've got a column where I save an array of jsons as a string, like this:

```
[
  {
  "id":0,
  "stops":[
     {
        "Id":0,
        "field1":"data1",
        "field2":"data2"
     }
  ],
  "time":"01:00:00"
  },

  {
  "id":2,
  "stops":[
     {
        "Id":0,
        "field1":"data1",
        "field2":"data2"
     }
  ],
  "time":"01:00:00"
  },
]
```

I want to count the number of jsons in this array. The database is in PostgreSQL 9.6.1.

Comment: In your example, is the expected output 2?4? Which database? (Mysql, sql server, etc?)

Comment: Sorry, the database is in PostgreSQL 9.6.1, and the output in this case, is 2.

Comment: `json_array_length()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the ***json_array_length()*** function to count, but if your column is of text type you will need to cast the column to become a json type, as follows:

```
json_array_length(cast(your_table.column_name as json))
```

Also, if you need to access your "stops" field, you could use ***json_array_elements()*** and do it like this:

```
json_array_elements( cast(your_table.column_name as json))->'Stops'
```

And to access even further, like fields inside "stop", you can just use the same function again:

```
json_array_elements( (json_array_elements( cast(your_table.column_name as json)))->'Stops')->'field1'
```

Hope I could help.